# Exit all called KornShell (ksh) scripts

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, exit-code

How can a KornShell (ksh) script exit/kill all the processes started from another ksh script?

If scriptA.ksh calls scriptB.ksh then the following code works good enough, but is there a better solution for this?:

**scriptA.ksh:**

```
#call scriptBSnippet
scriptBSnippet.ksh ${a}
```

**scriptB.ksh:**

```
#if error: exit this script (scriptB) and calling script (scriptA)#
kill ${PPID}
exit 1
```

To add complexity what if scriptA calls scriptB which calls scriptC, then how to exit out of all three scripts if there is an error in scriptC?

**scriptA.ksh:**

```
#call scriptBSnippet
scriptBSnippet.ksh ${a}
```

**scriptB.ksh:**

```
#if error: exit this script (scriptB) and calling script (scriptA)#
kill ${PPID}
exit 1
```

**scriptC.ksh:**

```
#if error: exit this script (scriptC) and calling scripts (scriptA, scriptB)#
#kill ${PPID}
#exit 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Killing all processes started by the same script is a bit of a brute force method.

It would be best to have some method of communication between the processes that would allow them to gracefully shutdown.

However, if all processes are in the same process group, you can send a signal to the entire process group:

```
kill -${Signal:?} -${Pgid:?}
```

Note that two arguments are required in this case.  A single argument starting with `-` is always interpreted as a signal.

Run some tests to see which processes get included in the process group.

parent.sh:

```
Shell=ksh
($Shell -c :) || exit

$Shell child1.sh & pid1=$!

$Shell child2.sh & pid2=$!

$Shell child3.sh & pid3=$!

ps -o pid,sid,pgid,tty,cmd $PPID $$ $pid1 $pid2 $pid3
exit
```

child.sh:

```
sleep 50
```

If you run `parent.sh` from a terminal - it will become the process leader.

granny.sh:

```
Shell=ksh
($Shell -c :) || exit

$Shell parent.sh & 

wait
exit
```

If you run `parent.sh` from another script `granny.sh`, then *that* will be the process group leader, and will be included when you use the `kill -SIG -PGID` method.

See also this answer to: 
[What are “session leaders” in `ps`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18178/15531) for some background on sessions and process groups.

Comment: These ksh scripts (scriptA,scriptB,scriptC) should be as decoupled as possible and each script should have as few input parameters as possible. This solution will require addition input parameters...

Comment: If each script can put itself in the same process group (Pgid) then this might work, so any insight on how to do that?

Comment: That should be the default.  Updated the answer to help you show.

Comment: This is a ksh question not a sh question:-)

Comment: I try to test solutions with multiple shells to see how they differ.   Fixed now :-)